# Angular @HostListener delay click until input is given if not use default values

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-directive

I am strugling to get this done.
What i'd like to achieve is the following.

I have a directive with an Input of attributes that this directive checks, but if no input is given it uses some defaults defined by the directive itself.
But the click handling itself is always happens before the Input value arrives. So it's always checks for wrong inputs (default ones).
I've tried to use some rxjs as well, but something is off.
The directive looks like this.

if I log the `exceptions` @`Oninit` subscription it's not even logging anything.
How can i tweak my directive to work as I need it to work?

Some code for better understanding

```
  private onChangeSub$ = new Subject<AutoSaveExceptions>();
  private readonly clicks$ = new Subject<HTMLElement>();
  private someStream$: Subscription;

  private subscription$: Subscription;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes && changes['exceptions'] && changes['exceptions'].firstChange === true) {
      this.onChangeSub$.next(changes['exceptions'].currentValue);
      console.log(changes['exceptions'].currentValue);
    }
  }

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('oninit');
    this.subscription$ = this.onChangeSub$.pipe(
      defaultIfEmpty(this.inlineDefaultExceptions)
      ).subscribe((exceptions) => {
      this.exceptionAttributes = exceptions;
    });
    this.someStream$ = this.clicks$.pipe(
      delay(300),
    ).subscribe((target) => this.handleClicks(target));
  }

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(target: HTMLElement) {
    this.clicks$.next(target);
  }
```

@Edit: 
[Basic idea reproduction without directive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdojsf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you must avoid using `@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])` in general. This can become source of major performance problems. Reason is for every instance of your directive/component that have this you register as many document clicks as many instances of directive/component you have, all of them will trigger change detection heavily. Beware of that.

What you should do instead if you want to have global clicks listened is something like this:

```
const documentClick$: Observable<MouseEvent> = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(publish(), refCount());
export const DOCUMENT_CLICK = new InjectionToken('DOCUMENT_CLICK', {providedIn: 'root', factory: () => documentClick$});
```

then inject it into your component/directive:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT_CLICK) private readonly documentClick$: Observable) {}
```

Then you can do any kind of rxjs magic with it and it will make sure that you will have a single document click listener in entire app at most. Less change detection running - better performance.

Now you can filter your click$ stream until you have changes:

```
this.documentClick$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.onChangeSub$) // should not emit anything further until this stream emits, if it does, just add a filter
  filter(([event, changes]) => ... ) // check that it's not default
).subscribe(() => ...) // handle there for example
```

**EDIT:**
Your directive can check editing state and inject the `elementRef` along with `documentClick$` I mentioned above, then when editing is enabled directive can listen a global click and handle it in way checking wether it was outside of our element and if so trigger event that will cause autosave.
Here is [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdojsf-qgvxgn?file=src%2Fautosave.directive.ts).

Comment: I have posted a second question related to what you've mentioned. I am facing that every instance of a component that is using this directive triggers the logic thou it shouldnt. Tomorrow i'll try out your solution.

Comment: how and where should I listen for global mouseclicks?

Comment: I've tried your solution if do not filter it it still does stuff multiplied by how many of the components i'Ve isung this duirective on exists on the page. If I use some filter logic then I get undefined as the last from changes sub. Also publish is not accepting any arguments for me.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am just too used to using `publishReplay(1)`, but it's not what you want here, so `publish()` is the way to do. I can help you better if you set up a stack blitz or something so I can see how it actually works and help you getting it work. Also of course it will execute code for every component, but you get only 1 global click listener which is important

Comment: just please tell me what exactly you're trying to achieve, maybe I can help come up with much simpler way of doing it

Comment: So we have a 3rd party inline-editor copy-pasted by some other ppl in the company for some input types. Because of the complexity of this i cannot really do a stackblitz, but i might try to reproduce some part of it, so you can tweak it.
What i'd like to achieve is the following (we have a save & cancel icons which acts as their names) But we'd like to add some autosave feature, so if the user clicks out from the currently used component an autosave occurs if changes are made and they are correct, otherwise cancel. 
I want to achieve this autosave behavior.
Meanwhile i'll work on stackblitz

Comment: it doesn't need to be exactly as complex as in real app, it's enough if you just reflect the concept

Comment: Added the basic stackblitz, i'll implement the directive shortly.

Comment: thank you for stakblitz, I will check when I have time and try to help you

Comment: Huge thanks! I tought about adding the directive, so i've decided to add it but it's empty so i'd not encourage my approach. So maybe you can come up with some other/better idea to manage this autosave stuff.

Comment: I modified your stackblitz and modified directive. That code there I just copied from a component I made half a year ago, but it seems to work for your case. Anyway you can adjust it to your needs at any point. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdojsf-qgvxgn?file=src%2Fautosave.directive.ts

Comment: It seems like working fine, i have to tweak some other aspects of the components but looking good and much more reliably than my approach. Can you add some comments @ the `EventHelper` class what are we looking for exactly

Comment: sure, I will comment it

Comment: Also on a sidenote can you post your final answer so i can upvote it for you? Thanks for the help again

Comment: I updated the stackblitz. You can see some extra comments there
gonna also update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Operator `defaultIfEmpty()` emits when its source Observable completes. However, your `onChangeSub$` is a Subject that only completes when you call `onChangeSub$.complete()` so you'll never receive the default value.

You might be looking for something like this instead:

```
timeoutWith(delay, of(this.inlineDefaultExceptions))
```